# WPF Entity Framework Foreign key won't load it's value in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mahapps.metro

I am using Entity Framework code first with fluent API I have an items table with foreign keys from users and units tables

but when I load the table to `ObservableCollection` then bind it to a `datagrid` the table normal column load it's data normally into the `datagrid` excpet for the foreign keys which show nothing but when i insert a break point to see the data inside the `ObservableCollection` I can see that every thing from Users and Units table is there

```
 private void MainContentsWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         using (var db2 = new DataContext())
         {
             var AllItems2 = new ObservableCollection<Model.Items.Item>(db2.Items);
             ItemsDataGrid.ItemsSource = AllItems2;
         }
    }
```

Users

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        IsActive = false;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public UserGroup Group { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Items.Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Items.Item>();
}

public enum UserGroup
{
    Administrator = 1,
    User,
    Unknown
}
```

base

```
public class NormalBaseModel : CommonBase
{
    public NormalBaseModel()
    {
        Id = new Guid();
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
        EditDate = null;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreateBy { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? CreateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual User EditBy { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? EditDate { get; set; }
}
```

items

```
public class Item : NormalBaseModel
{
    public string NameAr { get; set; }

    public string NameEn { get; set; }

    public int? ManualId { get; set; }

    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    public byte?[] Image { get; set; }

    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }

    public string MadeIn { get; set; }

    public bool IsSerail { get; set; }

    public bool IsExpire{ get; set; }

}
```

Here is a test project on `Github`
https://github.com/ahmedpiosol/psychic-parakeet.git

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oik19.jpg

Comment: What is the type of objects that represents the data? Try get the result of ToString() of that object.

Comment: Which columns are you referring to and what do you expect to show up in these?

Comment: @mm8 CreateBy - EditBy  should display the user name (binding it to combobox inside the datagrid with the id to SelectedValuePath and the name to the DisplayMemberPath)------------------------------------


Unit should display the unit name (binding it to combobox inside the datagrid)------------------------------


it will show "{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_AFE7D7BF55831864FA001BCFD2FB4677AA0872F4BBB6EC42336E7F7CA826EE21}" if i bind it directly

Comment: @mm8 nope but if i did i will get values like i mentioned above 
the whole project is on github the link is in the post
for the xaml code here it's
https://github.com/ahmedpiosol/psychic-parakeet/blob/master/src/Test/View/MainContentWindow.xaml

Comment: You can't bind the ItemsSource of a ComboBox to a User property...You should bind it to a collection of all users. Where is this one defined...?

Comment: i didn't also the project on github

https://github.com/ahmedpiosol/psychic-parakeet

Comment: sorry, you said "You can't bind the ItemsSource of a ComboBox to a User property" and i replied that i don't do that because the item model already have an virtual model of the user linked to that item which i want to show its name in the datagrid the user model already has the id name group etc
the ObservableCollection is the one binded to the datagrid which have all data in the Items table then the user model for each item there get binded to the combobox inside the datagrid so it show its name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluent API needs to specify foreign key in code, something like

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Items>()
             .HasRequired(o => o.User)
             .WithMany(c => c.Items)
             .HasForeignKey(o => o.UserId);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you load your items via EF it needs to create new instances of `User` and `Item`. Behind the scenes, EF will call the constructor for each new instance. Your problem is in your constructors:

```
public User()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(); // <- here
}
```

Your constructor reassigns a new ID each time an instance is created, this will break the referential integrity and cause all sorts of other problems.

Your code doesn't know the difference between creating a new `User` and *recreating a `User` instance from the database*.

I suggest removing the assignments from inside your constructor and placing this either in a static `Create` method or place wherever you are creating a new `User` or `Item`.

p.s. WPF is irrelevant to your problem here.

Comment: it get overwritten once it loads the actual data but to be sure i removed all of them still the same problem despite the fact that the data (related to the foreign keys) is there the datagrid can't display them 

https://imgur.com/a/zimd4